# Pass by reference impossible?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I'm trying to use a [for_each](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/for_each/) loop in my code, but I'm getting the following error:

```
cannot convert parameter 1 from 'std::pair<_Ty1,_Ty2>' to 'std::pair<_Ty1,_Ty2> &'
```

here's the offending code:

```
typedef stdext::hash_map<
        std::string, std::list<DefaultTestContext>
    > CompleteTestList;

static void RunMappedTests(pair<string, list<DefaultTestContext>>& tests)
{
    RunAllTestsInList(tests.second);
}

void RunTestsInParallel(CompleteTestList& testList)
{
    for_each(testList.begin(), testList.end(), RunMappedTests);
}
```

Of course, the easy fix is to change RunMappedTests's parameter to be pass-by-value instead of pass-by-reference. Unfortunately, in this case, it comes with a huge performance penalty. It will have to copy a string, AND a list of ~64 byte data blocks. The amount of copying done is scary. I also NEED to modify the original elements in the map.

Anyone dealt with this before? Any easy fixes I don't know about?

Comment: Microsoft extension to for_each. They're the same thing, except one's parallized. The same effect can be seen with for_each.

Comment: Alright, thanks. That should stop the "it's `parallel_for_each`" branch of questions. :P If this is C++0x, use `#include <unordered_map>` and `std::unordered_map` as the container, by the way. The `hash_map` extension is old and probably deprecated. Do you get the same issues if you change your container to a normal `map`? Your code looks fine to me. The only thing I could recommend is using your typedef; for the parameter of `RunMappedTests`, use `CompleteTestList::value_type` to ensure it's 100% correct. (and `typedef`'ing `std::list<DefaultTestContext>` couldn't hurt.)

Comment: Yes sir!

Templates lead to massively complex code, and even more complex errors...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`std::map<T1, T2>::value_type` is `std::pair<const T1, T2>`. Change the parameter of `RunMappedTests` to `pair<const string, list<DefaultTestContext>> &`.

Comment: Right, but the iterator should be dereferencing into a non-const reference. I feel this is an unsolution.

Comment: As long as the key is const it maintains the map's invariants.

Comment: @wowus: Eh, seems hackish. I'm curious if you get the same problems with a normal `map`.

Comment: Actually, it makes perfect sense. You can't modify the first element, and the string SHOULD be const. I need to read documentation closer next time. THANK YOU, OH GREAT MSN :)

Comment: Another way of saying the same thing: "Change the parameter to `CompleteTestList::value_type&`".